# Задача с массивом

Tags: python

Дан массив x, состоящий из латинских букв. Исключить из него элементы, стоящие на
чётных местах, затем элементы стоящие на нечётных местах упорядочить по неубыванию.
Вот что есть на данный момент:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for j in range(len(a)):
   if j % 2 == 0:
       del a[j-1]
print(a)
```

проблема в том, что он выдает неправильные значение, а почему понять не могу(дошел пока до удаления элементов)

Comment: Потому что удаляя элементы из начала вы тем самым смещаете те, что остались правее. Если идти от конца к началу, то такого не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно же слайсы использовать:

```
print(sorted(a[1::2]))
```

Но вообще чётность зависит от того, с нуля мы элементы считаем или с 1.

И лучше вообще не удалять ничего из имеющегося массива, а создавать новый (ну если только это не очень большой массив, из которого удаляется пара элементов). Удаление элементов "на ходу" это всегда какое-то шаманство, если и не будет ошибок, то код будет зачастую не очевидным.

Comment: О, круто. Забыл, что так можно)

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я тоже периодически напишу, думаю о, круто... и тут кто-нибудь ещё проще и короче напишет )  Питон такой....

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/90Htxb

```
a = ['z', 'a', 'q', 'v', 'e', 'w', 'w', 'w']
b = sorted(a[i] for i in range(0, len(a), 2))
print(b)
```